# Passing a function in for processing a CSV file: type error

Tags: haskell

Problem: Process a CSV file and test a condition on it. Current code simply prints instead of testing for the condition.

Issue: Type inference fails. I do not follow why it fails.

Here's the code, less the import boilerplate.

```
--------------------------------------------------
has_empty_string :: [String] -> Bool
has_empty_string col =
  any null col

----------------------------------------
get_hashrow :: [[String]] -> [String]
get_hashrow sheet =
  -- looking at column 5
  map (\row -> row !! 5) sheet

------------------------------
process_lines :: (String -> b) -> Handle -> IO ()
process_lines func inh = do
    ineof <- hIsEOF inh
    if ineof
      then return ()
      else do inpStr <- hGetLine inh
              result <- func inpStr
              putStrLn $ show result
              process_lines func inh


------------------------------
process_lines_in_file :: (String -> b) -> FilePath -> IO ()
process_lines_in_file func filename =
  do inh <- openFile filename ReadMode
         process_lines func inh

----------------------------------------
test_csv_row :: String -> Bool
test_csv_row row =
  has_empty_string ( get_hashrow ( readCSV row))

----------------------------------------
main :: IO ()
main = do
  [filename] <- getArgs
  process_lines_in_file test_csv_row filename
  return ()
```

And here's the error:

```
 Couldn't match expected type `b' against inferred type `IO a'
      `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for `process_lines' at content-hash-p.hs:29:28
    In a stmt of a 'do' expression: result <- func inpStr
    In the expression:
        do { inpStr <- hGetLine inh;
             result <- func inpStr;
               putStrLn $ show result;
             process_lines func inh }
    In the expression:
        if ineof then
            return ()
        else
            do { inpStr <- hGetLine inh;
                 result <- func inpStr;
                   putStrLn $ show result;
                 .... }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(In the future, please include the import boilerplate.)

Type inference is not failing -- since you're not asking the compiler to do any type inference! However, type-checking *is* failing. Let's see why.

You claim `process_lines :: (String -> b) -> Handle -> IO ()`. Experienced Haskeller's will already be shuddering at this type. Why? This type claims that its first argument can be *any* function at all which does something to a `String`. But this is an odd claim to make, since the return type of this function doesn't appear anywhere else in the type of `process_lines` -- meaning, we can call this function, but never use its result! Thanks to laziness, this means that the call will never actually happen.

So it's a weird type. Let's see if we can take the argument above and find out where it fails in your code; that should help point to the problem.

```
process_lines func inh = do
    ineof <- hIsEOF inh
    if ineof
      then return ()
      else do inpStr <- hGetLine inh
              result <- func inpStr -- HERE
              putStrLn $ show result
              process_lines func inh
```

Take a look at the line marked `HERE`. This is the only occurrence of `func` in our implementation. According to the argument above, we can never use the output of `func`, yet here we seem to be using the output of `func`. What type are we using it at? Well, we're using it at an `IO {- something -}` type, since it's in a `do`-block; furthermore, since we bind `result` and then call `show result`, the `{- something -}` must be some type that we can call `show` on -- that is, a member of the `Show` class. So the type of `func` is not as unrestricted as `String -> b`; it's the more restricted `Show b => String -> IO b`. A similar argument applies to `process_lines_in_file`, so that its updated type ought to be `process_lines_in_file :: Show b => (String -> IO b) -> FilePath -> IO ()`.

(Indeed, if you leave off the type signatures, type *inference* will infer exactly these types for you.)

Now that `process_lines_in_file` demands a function that does `IO`, we can no longer pass `test_csv_row` as-is. You can choose either to call `process_lines_in_file (return . test_csv_row) filename` in `main` or to change the implementation of `test_csv_row` to call `return` (which does the trivial IO action: no input or output, just do a pure computation and pretend it did IO).

With these changes, the code compiles.

Comment: "You can choose either to call process_lines_in_file (return . test_csv_row) filename in main or to change the implementation of test_csv_row to call return" OR you can replace `result <- func inpStr` with `let result = func inpStr`, change the type appropriately and then pass in `test_csv_row` unchanged, which might make a lot more sense.

Comment: Okay, I am not following what's going on 100%. That's not your fault though. :-)   What does `=>` actually mean? I tried to find a reference for it a while ago and couldn't dig up a good description. The one I did find rambled off into some formal semantics notation.

Comment: @Paul That's kind of a big question, depending on how comfy you are with type classes. Maybe the type class chapter in one of the tutorials would be an appropriate starting point, e.g. http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses or http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-typeclasses.html or http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/classes.html or even all three multiplexed.

Comment: @Daniel: Okay, loosely speaking, it states (or constrains to) membership in a type class. Yes?